# Encrypt Object via Laravel 5.7 PHP and Decrypt via VueJS Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, encryption, cryptojs

I have a Laravel 5.7 application which encrypts an object and returns the encrypted object to my VueJS application.

> **PLEASE NOTE** the below code is for explanation purposes and I am not
>   using in this way, however, the concept is.

**Laravel Function triggered by a route**

```
public function license() {
  var data = [{id: 1}, {expiry_date: '2019-02-25T10:47:12+00:00'}];
  $encrypted = \Crypt::encrypt(JSON.stringify(data));
  return $encrypted;
}
```

**Vue JS Method for Retrieving Object**

```
checkLicense() {
      this.$http.get(LARAVEL_ROUTE).then(res => {
        var key = 'LARAVEL_APP_KEY'; // NOT REAL
        var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(res.data, 'LARAVEL_APP_KEY');
        var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
      });
}
```

**The above produces the following:**

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Malformed UTF-8 data

**Things I've tried:**

- I have checked the LARAVEL_APP_KEY and I can see that it is prefixed
  with 'base64:' so I have tried removing this from my VueJS method
  where I declare the key but this made no difference.
- I have also removed the object and tried encrypting a string which
  produces the same result as above.

**Additional question:**

I'd also like to encrypt the string / object with something other than the LARAVEL_APP_KEY as I don't want to store that value in my VueJS application. The key doesn't need to be super secure however I would rather not use the LARAVEL_APP_KEY

Comment: Just have a look [here](https://laravel.io/forum/05-17-2016-encrypt-with-laravel-and-decrypt-with-js)

Comment: Thanks that worked! just need to figure out how to encrypt with a different key than the LARAVEL_APP_KEY now. - Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that the client will receive the encryption key when you do this meaning **all** encrypted strings with the same key will be decryptable by any user who receives that key. If you want to do this then generate a random encryption key for each user and store it in the database.

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, I would suggest the following.

Firstly, I'm not sure why you are wanting to encrypt data on the server and then decrypt on the client. The only benefit that I could see for that is to prevent MITM attacks, in which case you should be using SSL.

Secondly, I'm fairly sure that the encryption key is the base64 encoded value after the prefix `base64:`. So you will need to remove this and then base64 encode the remaining string in VueJS before trying to decrypt with the key.

In answer to your question about encrypting/decrypting with anything other than the APP_KEY, you can't have multiple keys that will decrypt the same value. Cryptography only works when you have the correct key.

I would really not recommend decrypting data on the client, anybody can then obtain your encryption key and if there was a vulnerability elsewhere and were able to access your database, they could decrypt any data that they like.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, to give some clarity. I have a VueJS application which is compiled to a desktop app using ElectronJS. This application is an offline application and I wanted a quick way to produce a license which expires after 12 months of use. The idea is that in the client (complied to an .exe) the license is decrypted and a check is done on the date. Again this is a super simple way of doing this however It's nothing too secure.

Comment: I should also add, I didn't want to store a raw date in the local database which can easily be edited.

Comment: Perhaps instead you could have the date, but to ensure it doesn't get edited you could also store a signature? That way as long as the signature is valid you know that the date hasn't been modified.

Comment: I'd love to know more on the concept? Do you have a link to some context? I'll have a Google - thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is an example to crypt from Laravel and decrypt with vueJS

**Laravel**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

public function encrypting(){

$string = 'This is example text';
$user = User::get();
// for simple string
$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString($string);
 
// for array , object
$encrypted2 = Crypt::encryptString(json_encode($user));

$response = [
    'user' => $user,
    'encrypted' => $encrypted,
    'encrypted2' => $encrypted2
];
}
```

**Action front server**

```
npm install crypto-js
```

**VueJS**

the key is the **APP_KEY** in **.env** (laravel) but remove **'Base64'** text :

```
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";

   Decrypting() {
   axios.get('http://back.domain.com/encrypting').then(response => {
    this.user = response.data.user;
    this.stringEncrypte = response.data.encrypted;
    this.userEncrypte = response.data.encrypted2;
    
    var key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx='
    var encrypted_json = JSON.parse(atob(this.userEncrypte));
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_json.value, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key), {
      iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted_json.iv)
    });
    // Decrypt in string format
    this.stringDecrypted = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    // Decrypt in Array, Object format
    this.userDecrypted = JSON.parse(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));


  })
},
```

Comment: You shouldn't make your app key public.

Comment: As @max said app key should not be made public. Instead of using `Crypt` that uses app key you should use `new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter($key)` where `$key` needs to be 16 characters for `AES-128-CBC` and 32 characters for `AES-256-CBC`. You can then use this key in vue